# Any way to search through your questions to find ones that have not been marked as answered?

Tags: support, questions, search, unanswered-questions

Basically, sometimes I forget to mark a question as answered, or I haven't had a chance to go and test the answer to see if it works for me.... so it ends up getting buried. Any way to easily search through your questions for "unanswered" questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for them using "[user:me hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20hasaccepted:0)." The search will show your questions where you didn't accept any answer, but also questions without an answer. You can try with "[user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20hasaccepted:0%20answers:1&submit=search)" and see if it shows the questions with at least an answer.

Comment: More search options can be seen at stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: ..and that upvote puts you at 10k! Congrats!